# SPFx - JavaScript function not firing

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a slide component assembled on my render()  method in my web part, it is displayed fine but the Javascript action **"ShowSlide()"** necessary to activate the slide is not being fired inside the **`$().ready()`**

I've placed the call inside the

```
public render(): void {  
  this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <!-- build the slide here -->
      <div>
         <ul>
            .....
            ..... shortened for brevity 
            .....
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- CALL THE SLIDE using $().ready() - it doesn't work -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() 
            ShowSlide();
        });
      </script>
  `;
}
```

I've ran out of ideas, I don't know what is preventing the function to be fired, I've added a little button to call this function manually and it works when it is called from pressing the button but not on the expected **`$().ready()`**

```
public render(): void {  
  this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <!-- manual call for ShowSlide() -- it works when clicked! -->
      <input type="button" value="Start Slide" onClick="ShowSlide()"  />
      <!-- build the slide here -->
      <div>
         <ul>
            .....
            ..... shortened for brevity 
            .....
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- CALL THE SLIDE using $().ready() - it doesn't work -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function()
            ShowSlide();
        });
      </script>
  `;
}
```

Comment: You're setting the element's `innerHTML`; while this does put the script in the DOM, it doesn't actually run it.

Comment: oh! i c what you are saying... it is the only place i'm familiar with for creating the HTML contents to assemble the slide (this works)... but getting to your point, where should I go with my function/slide to work?

Comment: I don't know how SPFx works at all, but I guess you can simply move the script to wherever you have `ShowSlide` defined?

Comment: hey Chris, the function I'm calling inside the SPFx is from my script externally sitting in the project 'jquery.slide.js' - I'm dealing with the firing of the function, I can call the function from the <input type="button" onclick="">

Comment: Sorry for asking but I assume you do have jQuery included?

Comment: yes I do have jQuery, it is loaded along with the other jQuery.Slide.js and Modernizr.JS - all show up fine, it is just finding on the TypeScript/SPFx how to get this thing in the right place to fire

Comment: Who's calling the render() function?

Comment: it is the web part, the start class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem! I learned about adding the script by creating the element inside HEAD, so all I had to do was the following:

```
  public render(): void {

    this.domElement.innerHTML = this.htmlContents;

    let head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement,
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    try {
        script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.htmlScript));
    } 
    catch (e) {
        script.text = this.htmlScript;
    }

    head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
    head.removeChild(script);               
  }
```

I hope this helps anybody out there facing the same problem, took me 4 straight days researching, googling, reading everything I could, till I found an article on a blog about calling Azure functions inside SPFx, from there I could get the inspiration to connect the points and solve my problem!

Comment: Works like a charm! VERY helpful!